# Is there any way to edit an entire CollectionView section all together?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am creating an app that has multiple sections of a collection view. To style the app, I wanted to apply a drop shadow to an entire section of the collection view rather than just a single cell. Currently I am populating all the cells as usual with the cellForItemAt (below)

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! todayViewCVCell

        //a couple buttons I set pictures to
        cell.checkboxOutlet.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "checkIconNOTselected"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.starOutlet.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "StarIconDeselected"), for: UIControlState.normal)

        //populating a label
        cell.todoNameLabel.text = todoClass[tempCellIndexes[indexPath.row]].todoName

        return cell
}
```

Then I have a section header for each section using the viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind function (below)

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader,withReuseIdentifier: "TodaySectionHeaderView", for: indexPath) as! TodayHeaderReusableView

        headerView.projectTitleLabel.text = projects[cellIndexesAboveZero[tempNum]]
        tempNum += 1

        return headerView
    }
}
```

I would like to add the drop shadow around each section like the "First Project" section, "Fourth Project" section, etc. Is there any way to do this as a whole (and ignore the incorrect numbering lol)? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

[This is my current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP9m4.png)

Comment: I get a 503 when trying to view the picture.

Comment: I just re-uploaded it, it was working for me I'm not sure why it was giving you an error.

Comment: Ok, I see it now; thanks.

Comment: If you change it from a table view to a collection view, you can use a grouped style. That may not be exactly what you want, but you'd get it out of the box.

Comment: This should get you where you want to go... it is setting a background color for each section, so it should be pretty easy to extend the idea to adding a drop-shadow: http://strawberrycode.com/blog/how-to-create-a-section-background-in-a-uicollectionview-in-ios-swift/

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll play around a little bit keeping these things in mind and see if I can get a drop shadow to work.